# Cant access to unix platform after perform net use /delete/yes

Tags: windows, batch-file, unix, jenkins

There is a bat file where I am require to map network drive a location and assign it to a drive letter to build stuff in window environment.After finish performing the code the script will remove the drive and will go to a location in unix to retrieve the data file. My code example as below

```
::This part is use to map network drive a location and assign drive letter 
FOR /F "token=2" %%A IN (
'net use * "\\linux_server_1\data\username\item"'
) DO IF NOT %AA.==command. SET DRIVELETTER=%%A

:: Remove DRIVELETTER AFTER USE

net use %DRIVELETTER% /delete/yes
```

The bat file is executed in jenkins window batch command box.

When I try to access to unix path it says path specified not found.I check console output it says that there is still connection to the file on this drive I assume that it is still connecting and it is still pointing to the assign DRIVELETTER.I tried to point to the WORKSPACE by cd %WORKSPACE% which is the D drive it does not work either. The only solution I made so far that is open another window batch after the window batch then it could only access to the unix location.

Is there any other way to completely remove or disconnect the drive assigned in order to access unix location?

Comment: You are missing a percent symbol here: `IF NOT %AA.==command. SET DRIVELETTER=%%A`. Regardless of that I do not understand what you are trying to do. Your description makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Squashman the bat file has those command above and it is called in jenkins. I want to access to a unix location after `net use /delete`and it does not allows me to access it after remove network drive .I found out that that the drive is not completely disconnected which leads to path not found when access to unix location.I have to create another window batch command box in jenkins that it exits the batch file then only that I can access unix location. Let say the assigned drive is D after delete D the jenkins console show D I try cd to C:\Users\Test it does not point to C it still shows D.

Comment: Instead of `IF NOT %%A.==command.` I would write `IF NOT DEFINED DRIVELETTER`, so the approach is less dependent on locale settings; this does not solve your issue though, which I do not understand... Ah, and remove the `/yes` from the last line...

Comment: use `cd /d C:\Users\Test `. `cd` without `/d` sets only the directory to use on C: without really switching to the drive.

Comment: I think best for your task without the need to specify user name and password according to posted batch code would be using `pushd` at beginning of the batch file and `popd` at end. Run those two commands with `/?` as parameter in a command prompt window to get them explained by output help.

Comment: Please post all your code so that people can understand what you are trying to do.  The problem you are having may look like it is coming from one point in your code but many times it is coming from something else that you do not think is causing the problem because you do not have enough experience with batch.  I have seen this time and time again on a daily basis here at SO.